# How get entity class type from sub aggregation Set collection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I realize custom repository and try because we use Spring Data Jdbc 2.7 which is not supporting `InsertOnlyProperty` and in SQL generation I try to get class of sub aggregation for using in `context.getRequiredPersistentEntity`. How can I get it from `RelationalPersistentProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i get it from `RelationalPersistentProperty`?

[`getComponentType()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentProperty.html?is-external=true#getComponentType())

As the documentation says:

> Returns the component type of the type if it is a Collection. Will return the type of the key if the property is a Map.